# Using COUNTIF with text in a cell

Tags: excel, countif

I'm trying to use this function to search through a range, and find how many instances of the text which is in the cell to the left occurs.

```
=COUNTIF(K2:K201,VALUE(K205))
```

Sorry just for clarification: 
I mean not having to write this.

```
=COUNTIF(K2:K201,"Rolls/Sandwiches")
```

If the text is in the cell to the left.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the VALUE():

```
=COUNTIF(K2:K201,K205)
```